# A question about MKPinAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Wish to specify the the color of a map pin other than the default red.  From documentation, the MKPinAnnotationView class has a pinColor property where we can set the color.  My question is : what is the proper way to associate this pinColor property with an annotation object?

Wish that somebody knowledgable on this could help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you question correctly. 
I guess that would be part of your logic and that there's no one "correct" answer.
In one app I might have a plist containing definitions of all the objects in my app and their properties. In another more simple app I might just specify the color based upon an index when it's created for example.

If you just want to know how to set a property then follow Shrey's advice above

Comment: Have used statements similar to "[mapView addAnnotation : mp_0];" (where mp_0  is an annotation object) to add annotations.  My question is how to associate PinView objects (like those from @Shrey's answer) to an annotation object.

Answer (score 2):

i think only three colors are defined for `pinColor` property.

```
enum {
   MKPinAnnotationColorRed = 0,
   MKPinAnnotationColorGreen,
   MKPinAnnotationColorPurple
};
typedef NSUInteger MKPinAnnotationColor;
```

Here's the method to define it.

```
MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                             initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:MyAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, it shows how to create a view object with a specified color.  But how do we associate the view object with the actual annotation objects?

Comment: All the answers to your question, lies in this sample buddy..

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for your link to the sample code and your kind assistance.